# c++ templated static class with a const array of function pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, static, function-pointers

So I really need a class with the following structure, where the class is templated and `arr` is an array of function pointers, but I can't seem to figure out the proper syntax:

--myclass.h--

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    typedef void (*fptr)(std::vector<T> data);
    static void foo(std::vector<T> data);
    static void bar(std::vector<T> data);
    static void baz(std::vector<T> data);
    static const fptr arr[3];
};
```

--myclass.cpp--

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <vector>

template <typename T> void MyClass<T>::foo(std::vector<T> data) { ... }
template <typename T> void MyClass<T>::bar(std::vector<T> data) { ... }
template <typename T> void MyClass<T>::baz(std::vector<T> data) { ... }

template <typename T> MyClass<T>::fptr MyClass<T>::arr[3] = { &foo, &bar, &baz };
```

If it helps, my ultimate goal is for a fourth member function to call either `foo`, `bar`, or `baz` from the array so I can avoid the overhead of multiple if-else statements (my actual implementation has closer to 50 of these functions). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You have a lot of unrelated syntax errors (extra semi-colons, extra `static` keywords, incorrect typedef, conflicting names, ...). Fix those before asking your question. Better yet, provide a compilable example and ask about how to add what you want to it.

Comment: You are aware of [templates and headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file), are you? And are you sure you really want to *copy* the vectors in all functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fptr` is declared `const`, so define it `const` too. Also, because `Sort` is a template, you need `typename` to refer to `MyClass<T>::fptr`.

```
template<typename T>
const typename MyClass<T>::fptr MyClass<T>::arr[] = { &foo, &bar, &baz };
```

Side note: you won't be able to put this definition or the definitions of your static functions in a source file since they are templates.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81350f7563176f8a)

Moreover, consider using `using` instead of `typedef`, and `std::array` instead of a raw array:

```
using fptr = void (*)(std::vector<T>);
static const std::array<fptr, 3> arr;
// [...]
template<typename T>
const std::array<typename MyClass<T>::fptr, 3> MyClass<T>::arr = { &foo, &bar, &baz };
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b409f3c6dc918c5)

> Is there a better way to do this?

Probably, but I can't say without more details abour what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Sorry for all of the unrelated errors. Hopefully I fixed those in the edits to make things clearer. I just didn't want to copy-paste 700 lines of code.

Comment: What is the advantage of using `std::array` over a raw array?

Comment: @KodyPuebla Consistent interface with other standard containers... You get iterators, `std::array` passed as reference preserves its type (whereas arrays decay to pointers), so e. g. size remains usable, ...

Comment: @KodyPuebla Its methods, the fact that it doesn't decay into a pointer, and taste. Without any overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Move the whole class template into the .hpp file and initialize `arr` with the same signature as it was declared:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    typedef void (*fptr)(std::vector<T> data);

    static void foo(std::vector<T> data) {}
    static void bar(std::vector<T> data) {}
    static void baz(std::vector<T> data) {}

    static const fptr arr[3];
};

template <typename T>
const typename MyClass<T>::fptr MyClass<T>::arr[] = { &foo, &bar, &baz };
```

You may also define `arr` directly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    typedef void (*fptr)(std::vector<T> data);

    static void foo(std::vector<T> data) {
        for(int i : data) std::cout << "foo " << i << "\n";
    }
    static void bar(std::vector<T> data) {
        for(int i : data) std::cout << "bar " << i << "\n";
    }
    static void baz(std::vector<T> data) {
        for(int i : data) std::cout << "baz " << i << "\n";
    }
public:
    static constexpr std::array<fptr,3> arr = { &foo, &bar, &baz };
};

int main() {
    MyClass<int> a;
    a.arr[0](std::vector<int>(1));
    a.arr[1](std::vector<int>(2));
    a.arr[2](std::vector<int>(3));
}
```

Output:

```
foo 0
bar 0
bar 0
baz 0
baz 0
baz 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::function` and store them into a vector. Here is what I have come up with so far.

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class MyClass {
private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(std::vector<T>)>> myFuncs_;

public:
    MyClass() = default;

    void addFunc( std::function<void(std::vector<T>)> func ) {
        myFuncs_.push_back(func);
    }

    void caller(unsigned idx, std::vector<T> v ) {
        return myFuncs_.at(idx)( v );
    }

    static void foo(std::vector<T> data) {
        std::cout << "foo() called:\n";

        for (auto& d : data)
            std::cout << d << " ";
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    static void bar(std::vector<T> data) {
        std::cout << "bar() called:\n";

        for (auto& d : data)
            std::cout << d << " ";
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        MyClass<int> myClass;
        std::vector<int> a{ 1,3,5,7,9 };
        std::vector<int> b{ 2,4,6,8,10 };

        std::function<void(std::vector<int>)> funcA = MyClass<int>::foo;
        std::function<void(std::vector<int>)> funcB = MyClass<int>::bar;
        myClass.addFunc( funcA );
        myClass.addFunc( funcB );

        myClass.caller(0, a);
        myClass.caller(1, b);       

    } catch( std::runtime_error& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}
```

*-Output-*

```
MyClass::foo() was called:
1 3 5 7 9
MyClass::bar() was called:
2 4 6 8 10
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you was looking for. In this example `MyClass::caller(...)` takes two parameters, the index into the vector for which function pointer you want, and the parameter or data that the function requires as input.